# "Crystal Reports for Eclipse" in Eclipse Luna 4.4

Tags: eclipse, crystal-reports, eclipse-luna

Did anyone succeed in using Crystal Reports 4 Eclipse with Eclipse Luna 4.4 Java EE? If so, which plugins are required? Or isn't it posible at all?

**ANSWER:**

Crystal Reports für Eclipse is deprecated now and will not be developed further. Therefore we also can't expect neither full support for Java 8 nor Eclipse 4.4, and so it is finally reason enought to switch to Jasper Reports completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's highly unlikely to be supported yet - Eclipse 4.4 was only released just over a week prior to this question being asked. In general though, you'll need the same set of plugins required for prior versions of Eclipse that are supported, just the newer versions of them.

Generally, it takes a little while after release to check for (and fix) breaking changes introduced by newer versions of Eclipse.  Your best bet is to contact SAP for a timeline on official support.